# Como retornar erros ajax com jquery no Laravel 5.6

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Pelo que li na documentação, quando usando ajax, a resposta é sempre retornada em json, porém não consigo receber a informação para printar.

A mensagem retornada no console é:

```
http://localhost/projeto/cadastra/usuario 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

e os detalhes

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {email: ["validation.unique"]}}
errors:{email: ["validation.unique"]}
message:"The given data was invalid."
```

e meu código ajax é:

```
$('#cad_usu').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();                    
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('cadastra/usuario') }}",
        data: $(this).serializeArray(), //$(this).serialize() tentei tbm
         type: 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
             console.log(data.message);                                                         
             $('#retorno').html(data.message); //data.responseJSON tentei tbm
          }
    });
});
```

faltou o controller

```
public function cadastra(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'nome' => 'required|max:55',
        'email' => 'required|unique:usuarios',
        'senha' => 'required',
    ]);

    $c = new Usuario();
    $c->nome = $request->nome;
    $c->email = $request->email;
    $c->senha = Hash::make($request->senha);
    $c->save();
}
```

Comment: Já tentou acessar via `data.message`?

Comment: Tentei sim, tentei tambem com responseJSON, que vi em outras dicas, mas é como se ele estivesse matando a aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui deixo para caso servir para algum novato como eu o que eu consegui:
Adaptei esse código baseado nesta dica:
https://www.jesseqli.com/using-ajax-in-laravel-5-form-request-error-handling/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#xx').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        /*$.ajaxSetup({ //parte opcional, recomendada pela documentação do Laravel
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name='csrf-token']').attr('content')
            }
        });*/

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('xx') }}
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            //processData: false,
            //contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                $('#suc').html(data);
            },
            error: function( data )
            {
                if(!data.responseJSON){
                    console.log(data.responseText);
                    $('#err').html(data.responseText);
                }else{
                    $('#err').html('');
                    $.each(data.responseJSON.errors, function (key, value) {
                        $('#err').append(key+": "+value+"<br>");
                        //console.log(key);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pela sua mensagem de erro no retorno json parece que o email é uma chave unica definida como forma de validação `email: ["validation.unique"]`

Primeiro verifique os dados que são enviados via ajax:

- Eles estão sendo enviados?
- Estão corretos para serem validados?

(Não esqueça que para requisições ajax é necessário que o token esteja correto na solicitação)

Você pode verificar os dados das seguinte forma:

Adicione:
`console.log($(this).serializeArray());` antes de fazer a requisição ajax e confira os dados no console do navegador.

Segundo, verifique a regra de validação dos dados no seu controller e tente retornar os dados via json no controller logo após fazer a validação:

```
return response()->json($request->all());
```

No seu retorno Json pode colocar somente:

```
console.log(data);
```

Outro detalhe que pode verificar é seu arquivo de rotas, o link passado no ajax está definido como POST?

Você pode ter mais detalhes sobre erros das chamadas ajax com o seguinte:

```
success: function( conteudo ) {
    console.log(conteudo);
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(jqXHR + " - " + jqXHR.getResponseHeader() + " - " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown + " - " + errorThrown.message);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, respondendo sua pergunta, o criei o "erro" propositalmente para saber qual o comportamento do Laravel e também para não ter de ficar olhando toda hora no console, enquanto estiver em desenvolvimento. O que percebi é que quando são erros de validação utilizando o validador do Laravel, ele sempre retorna vetores json através de `responseJSON` do ajax, mas quando são erros diversos de sql por exemplo, ele retorna json, mas sem ser por vetor através do `responseText`. Vou postar a solução em que cheguei para facilitar o desenvolvimento, usando `jquery` ou `javascript`.

Comment: Costumo forçar os erros nesses casos tbm, no caso de não ser ajax eu uso o dd(); que ajuda um monte.